# There is an error using CMUCL

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

When staring cmucl with quicklisp, i get the following error:

```
Error in KERNEL::UNDEFINED-SYMBOL-ERROR-HANDLER:  the function GENERATE-CRC32-TABLE is undefined.
[Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

Restarts:
0: [CONTINUE       ] Return NIL from load of #P"/home/***/.cache/common-lisp/cmu-19f__19f_-freebsd-x86/home/***/quicklisp/quicklisp/deflate.sse2f".
1: [TRY-RECOMPILING] Recompile deflate and try loading it again
2: [RETRY          ] Retry Loading component: ("quicklisp" "deflate").
3: [ACCEPT         ] Continue, treating
                   Loading component: ("quicklisp" "deflate") as having
                   been successful.
4:                   Return NIL from load of #P"home:quicklisp/setup.lisp".
5:                   Return NIL from load of "home:.cmucl-init".
6: [ABORT          ] Skip remaining initializations.

Debug  (type H for help)

(KERNEL::UNDEFINED-SYMBOL-ERROR-HANDLER "<error finding name>"
    #.(SYSTEM:INT-SAP #x47FD70D4)
    #<Alien (*
        SYSTEM:SYSTEM-AREA-POINTER) at #x47FD6DC0>
    (16))
Source: Error finding source: 
Error in function DEBUG::GET-FILE-TOP-LEVEL-FORM:  Source file no longer exists:
   target:code/interr.lisp.
```

How can i fix it, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is to use a recent version of CMUCL.

Comment: >pkg_info -Qx cmucl
cmucl-19f_2:The CMU implementation of Common Lisp

Comment: Try getting it from cmucl.org instead of a package system. The package system is out of date.

Comment: I will try http://www.cmucl.org/downloads/release/20c/cmucl-20c-x86-freebsd_8.2-stable.tar.bz2 as there is no release for freebsd 9.x.